# Iterating through an array nested inside of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

thank you for the help in advance! Please forgive me if this is a stupid question as I a JS noobie.

I am trying to cycle through an array of URL's that I have nested inside of an object. What I am expecting to happen is for the url's (which are google maps) to show up on my website and for the person using my website to be able to click back and forth between the different map URL's. Right now what's happening is the last item (a google maps url) of myCities.index is being properly displayed, but when I click my previous and next buttons it is going to a blank page. I have looked at my JS console and there are no visible errors there. Can anyone give me some advice as to how to fix this? My code is as follows.

```
const myCities = {
  index:
    [url1, url2, url3]
}

const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const map = document.getElementById("myCitiesss");

nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextCity);
prevButton.addEventListener('click', prevCity);

function prevCity() {
  myCities.index--;
  updateSrc();
  checkButtons();
}

function nextCity() {
  myCities.index++;
  updateSrc();
  checkButtons();
 }

function updateSrc() {
  map.src = myCities.index;
}

function checkButtons() {
  prevButton.disabled = false;
    nextButton.disabled = false;  
  if (myCities.index === 2) {
    nextButton.disabled = true;
  }if (myCities.index === 0) {
prevButton.disabled = true;
}

}

updateSrc();
checkButtons();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're treating `myCities.index` as both the container of your data *and* as a counter (hence you're running incrementation/decrementation operations on it).

The counter should be a separate variable.

```
const myCities = [url1, url2, url3]; //<-- can now be a flat array
let index = 0; //<-- this is our counter, i.e. tracker
```

The relevant code changes are then: (I also took the opportunity to demonstrate some optimisations and efficiencies you can make)

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => nextPrevCity('next'));
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => nextPrevCity('prev'));

function nextPrevCity(which) { //<-- one function to handle both next and prev
    which == 'next' ? index++ : index--;
    map.src = myCities[index];
    checkButtons();
}

function checkButtons() {
    prevButton.disabled = false;
    nextButton.disabled = false;  
    if (index === myCities.length - 1) //<-- check against array length, not fixed number 2
        nextButton.disabled = true;
    if (!index) //<-- because 0 is a falsy value, so same as "if (index === 0)"
        prevButton.disabled = true;
}
```

[ -- EDIT -- ]

Forgot the following at the bottom of the code:

```
map.src = myCities[0];
checkButtons();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this incredibly helpful learning opportunity!

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO. I made a few edits/corrections so be sure to refresh.

Comment: One more question, with this answer do you know why it'd start off with showing an error of cannot GET / undefined before clicking the next button, but after clicking it that error clears and it starts at position [0] on the array?

Comment: See edit - I forgot to modify the last part of your code, the two function calls. If you still have an issue, post it up as a JS Fiddle and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JetimLee/gn29f4Lq/2/ edited with your edit, still had the same issue! :D

Comment: You hadn't quite changed the last line to what I put in my edit - you were still calling `nextPrevCity()` rather than just `map.src = myCities[0]`. https://jsfiddle.net/x0mfh8ts/